# Generate JNI Bridge and Java interfaces from C++

Tags: java, c++, code-generation, codebase

I know that it is possible to generate the JNI given a Java implementation using `javac` but is there a way to do the opposite (a "`cjava`")?

So if I have something like this:

`mypackage/mylib.h`:

```cpp
void helloWorld();
```

`mypackage/mylib.c`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

void helloWorld() {
    std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
}
```

Shouldn't it be possible to generate the JNI like

`mylib-jni.c`:

```cpp
#include "mypackage/mylib."

JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_mypackage_helloWorld() {
    helloWorld();
}
```

and

`Mylib.java`:

```java
package mypackage;

public class Mylib {    
    public native void helloWorld();    
}
```

etc.

Somehow I am not stumbling upon something like that.

Comment: Have you looked at [JNA](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/master/www/GettingStarted.md) (and the related [JNAerator](https://github.com/nativelibs4java/JNAerator)) or [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/)?

Answer (score 0):

Try antlr. It has a grammar file for C++ and gives you full control.

For the generation of java you could use the cgV19 i hust released. My picture is:

parse the C++ file with antlr and build a model loader for cgV19 with it.
cgV19 uses this C++ parser to load a model
give cgV19 a cartridge that can generate your java files from that model